# 2002 Jeep Liberty 3.7. Not firing on bank 1, black smoke along with gas smell. No codes

Tags: jeep, liberty

Thanks in advance for reading. I have a 2002 Jeep Liberty that dies on my wife one day. We towed it to a shop and they couldn't figure out whats wrong. The Jeep is not firing on bank 1, puts out black smoke (I assume from bank 1) and smells of gas when it starts (it will start but barely run) The plugs on bank one are black and smell of gas. No codes present and the check engine light did not come on. I have the catalytic converter from bank one pulled off now and there was no blockage that I can see but the honeycomb inside is pretty worn out. Does anyone have suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! It sounds like the ignition isn't fire on bank one, which might just be a fuse is blown. Check there first. Injectors are firing, so its not a fueling issue. If its only running on three cylinders, it's going to be running pretty crappy.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just to be cover all my bases I replaced the plugs on bank 1 and cleaned the o2 sensors, it’s firing now for reasons I can’t figure out but it barely holds an idle and runs really rough.

Comment: You "cleaned the O2 sensors"? Without doing a live data view, I couldn't tell you for sure, but you REALLY should not have done that. It's a good way to ruin them.

Comment: Just soaked the electrodes in gas for awhile to get some of the carbon off.

Comment: If you soaked the business end (part which stick into the exhaust pipe) with gasoline, you've most likely killed your O2 sensor(s). Time to replace it.

Comment: Dang. What’s strange is that I’m still not getting any codes and no check engine light

Comment: You may not get codes.